# Como implenetar Enum en java, poo

Tags: java, poo, enum

Estoy empezando a ver el tema de `enum` en java y tengo un ejercicio en el que me pide que compruebe en que cuadrante del plano cartesiano estan ciertos puntos, estos puntos estan almacenados en una ArrayList y el profesor me dijo que a traves de un `enum` yo podria averiguar en que cuadrante podria estar el punto que se este analizando y tambien me podria decir si uno de esos puntos no tiene cuadrante (una o dos de las coordenadas X e Y tiene valor 0).
El problema es que no se me ocurre como utilizar el `enum`, alguien que me ayude? estoy empezando con eso de la la poo.

les paso las clases:

```
package arraylist;

public class Punto {

    private Double x;
    private Double y;

    public Punto(Double x, Double y) {
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    public Punto(Double xy) {
        this(xy, xy);
    }

    public Punto() {
        this(0.0);
    }

    public Double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(Double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setY(Double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Double calcularDistancia(Punto punto) {
        return Math.hypot(this.getX() - punto.getX(), this.getY() - punto.getY());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getX() + "," + this.getY();
    }

    public int getcuadrante() {

        int cuadrante = 0;

        if(x>0 && y>0) {
            cuadrante = 1;
        }
        if(x<0 && y>0) {
            cuadrante = 2;
        }
        if(x<0 && y<0) {
            cuadrante = 3;
        }
        if(x>0 && y<0) {
            cuadrante = 4;
        }
        return cuadrante;
    }

}
```

---

```
package arraylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Plano {


    private ArrayList<Punto> Puntos;



    public ArrayList<Punto> getPuntos() {
        return Puntos;
    }

    public Plano() {
        this.setPuntos(new ArrayList<Punto>());
    }

    public void agregarPunto(Punto punto) {
        this.getPuntos().add(punto);
    }

    public Integer getCantPuntos(Cuadrante cua) {
        Integer cont = 0;
        for(Punto punto: this.getPuntos()) {
            if(punto.getcuadrante(cua.getX(),cua.getY()).equals(cua)) {
                cont++;
            }
            return cont;
        }
    }

    public void setPuntos(ArrayList<Punto> puntos) {
        Puntos = puntos;
    }


}
```

---

```
package arraylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UsoArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args ) {

        ArrayList<Punto> vector = new ArrayList<Punto>();

        System.out.println("Tamaño: " + vector.size());



    }
}
```

Lo que ahi estaria faltando seria el enumerador, pero no se como implementarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero sería declarar la enumeración:

```
enum Cuadrante {
    UNO, DOS, TRES, CUATRO
}
```

Después cambiarías la función getCuadrante:

```
public Cuadrante getCuadrante() {
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        return Cuadrante.UNO;
    }

    if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
        return Cuadrante.DOS;
    }

    if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
        return Cuadrante.TRES;
    }

    return Cuadrante.CUATRO;
}
```

He quitado el último if de la función ya que no es necesario

Comment: muchas gracias!